# execution time serial and parallel openmp program mac os

Tags: c++, macos, performance, parallel-processing

I have a problem in understanding the execution time of my program (serial and parallel version).

Here you can find the part of the main function I am talking about:

```
stopwatch temp2;
temp2.start();
#pragma omp parallel
{

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
        int a=itemVectorTraining->at(mapScaledItem->at(5755)).timesIWatchedAfterC(itemVectorTraining->at(mapScaledItem->at(236611)), deviceVectorTraining, 180);
    }
}
temp2.stop();

cout<<"Parallel: "<<temp2.elapsed_ms()<<endl;

stopwatch temp1;
temp1.start();

for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
    int a=itemVectorTraining->at(mapScaledItem->at(5755)).timesIWatchedAfterC(itemVectorTraining->at(mapScaledItem->at(236611)), deviceVectorTraining, 180);
}

temp1.stop();

cout<<"Serial: "<<temp1.elapsed_ms()<<endl;
```

where "stopwatch" is an object well defined (I hope so, since my professor has created it :) ) in order to have a corrected measure of time in milliseconds.

The problem is that when I execute the main with this command line:

```
g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -o test -Iinclude main.cpp
```

I obtain this output

```
Parallel: 140821125 
Serial: 89847
```

while adding "-fopenmp", i.e. with this command line:

```
g++-4.9 -fopenmp -std=c++11 -o testVale main.cpp
```

I get:

```
Parallel: 39413
Serial: 2089786185294
```

And it doesn't make any sense! Moreover while the program return me such big values for Parallel in the first case and for Serial in the second case, actually it doesn't take such a long time to run the code.

I am compiling from the terminal of a MAC OS X , and normally I should obtain something like:

```
Parallel:38548 
Serial 68007
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on with the compilation of the program?

Thank you very much!

Code of stopwatch:

```
    #ifndef CGLIFE_STOPWATCH_HPP
#define CGLIFE_STOPWATCH_HPP

#include <chrono>

class stopwatch {
private:
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;
    bool running;
    clock::time_point start_time;
    clock::duration elapsed;
public:
    stopwatch() {
        running = false;
    }
    // Starts the stopwatch.
    void start() {
        if (!running) {
            running = true;
            start_time = clock::now();
        }
    }
    // Stops the stopwatch.
    void  stop() {
        if (running) {
            running = false;
            elapsed += clock::now() - start_time;
        }
    }
    // Resets the elapsed time to 0.
    void reset() {
        elapsed = clock::duration();
    }
    // Returns the total elapsed time in milliseconds.
    // If the stopwatch is running, the elapsed time
    // includes the time elapsed in the current interval.
    long long elapsed_ms() const {
        clock::duration total;
        if (!running) {
            total = elapsed;
        } else {
            total = elapsed + (clock::now() - start_time);
        }
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(total).count();
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: The numbers got from stopwatch::elapsed_ms() seem random, like value of some uninitialized member. If you want any help with it then post the code of stopwatch class.

Comment: Thank you! I have included in my question the code of stopwatch class. Anyway since the same program (with the same stopwatch class) works on the Virtual Machine of Windows PC , I suppose there is some mistake in my command line. 

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stopwatch::elapsed` seems uninitialized. I am unsure how it can be, since it must be of a class type.
Either initialize it in `stopwatch` constructor:

```
stopwatch() {
    running = false;
    elapsed = clock::duration();
}
```

or call `reset` always before starting one:

```
stopwatch temp2;
temp2.reset();
temp2.start();
```